# Undergraduate Complex Analysis: Use of Rouche's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, complex-geometry

We are asked to prove
$
f = z^{3}e^{1-z} = 1 
$
has exactly 2 roots inside $|z| = 1$

We've tried creating functions $p$ and $q$ where $p + q = f$, $p$ with 2 roots inside our boundary,  and using Rouche's Thm, but we keep on getting equality. I feel like we're missing something. Any hints or direction is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.